# In javascript function calling var to another page through session or localstorage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

Im to trying to send javascript response to another page by using localstorage or by using session but im unable to get response here is javascript fun below eg
page1.php

```
  function data(responseData) {
alert(responseData.dataValue);  eg:name   //here im getting data    
alert("Total = "+responseData.dataValue);
      $("#submit-link").attr('href',"https://example.com/paymentdata.php?totalScore="+total);
}
```

page2.php
Here i called the link

```
    <button id="process">Process</button>
<br />
<a href="#" id="submit-link">links</a> // i want that name here
```

I have tried i got nothing. All i want from page1.php data get in page2.php  data i have tried through session also no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the browser local storage you can pass any data between any pages in your website. If you have more complex data like an object you have to stringify/parse to get it to work, but otherwise a string or integer will work fine.

```
window.localStorage.setItem('key', 'a string value');
window.localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(YourValueAsObject));

var getValueFromLS = window.localStorage.getItem('key');
var getValueFromLSParsed = JSON.parse(getValueFromLS);
```

Comment: It works exactly what i was expecting. Thank you @Thomas Juranek